# Changing Host side code for openCL C++ after stringifying the kernel code

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl, stringification

I am working on a project where I am using openCL C++ bindings. I have a kernel.cl file that is read from the host side and loaded and executed. But now I want to embed it into my .cpp file so I can distribute the binary file without the kernel.cl file.

I applied the STRINGIFY method, but I don't know what else to change and which lines of code to change?

**Previous code:**

**main.cpp**

```
// Load in kernel source, creating a program object for the context
cl::Program programGA(context, loadProgram
                               ("../src/path/kernelGA.cl"),
                              true);

// Create the kernel functor
auto kernelGA = cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer,
                                cl::Buffer,
                                cl::Buffer,
                                cl::Buffer,
                                cl::Buffer>
                                (programGA, "kernelGA");

// CREATE THE BUFFERS.
d_buff = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
                                (Length * P_SIZE * sizeof(double)),
                                asd);
....and so on...

// Enqueue the kernel.
kernelGA(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue[iter],
                                   cl::NDRange(P_SIZE / numberOfDevices)),
                                   d_buff1,
                                   d_buff2,.. and so on..);

// Enqueue in the corresponding device.
queue[iter].finish();
```

Now I applied the STRINGIFY method but I don't know which parts of the code to change and how to change them. Because now the kernel should be read from the stringifiedSourceCL and according to that, I should change my program to read from stringifiedSourceCL rather than from the file.

**AFTER STRINGIFYING:**

```
// in main.cpp
#define STRINGIFY(src) #src
char * stringifiedSourceCL =
#include "kernelGA.cl"
```

What other parts should I change? Does anyone know of a good tutorial with openCL C++ bindings that shows how to run the program with Stringified kernels rather than from .cl files? Which direction should I go in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no problem here. Just:

```
// in main.cpp
#define STRINGIFY(src) #src
const char * stringifiedSourceCL =
#include "kernelGA.cl"

...

// Creating a program object for the context
cl::Program programGA(context, stringifiedSourceCL, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a `cl::Program` using a string instead of the file name.
That is all you have to do :)

Check the [API](http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html).